# Generalized numpy point-matrix multiplication function that produces consistent outputs with inputs of varying shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I want to make a generalized function that does point-matrix transformations with inputs of varying shapes, using the following definitions:

- Array `p` is an array of points of any shape, with leaf elements of xyz vectors such as: (Parent shape P,...,leaf xyz vector p)
- Array `M` is an array of matrices of any shape, with leaf elements of shape (4,4) matrices such as: (Parent shape M,...,leaf (4,4) shape)
- The desired output should have the shape: `(Parent shape M, Parent shape P, leaf xyz vector p)`

Because i'm not quite clear as to how `numpy.dot` orders its output, i came up with a clumsy shape matching scheme. I look at the shape of `numpy.dot`, walk it until i find the index of the matching matrix "container shape", and then use the info to reshape the result into the desired input.

Here's the code i came up with:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

def pointMatrixMultiply(p,M):
    """ Multiplies an array of 3D points p by an array of 4x4 transformation (4x4) matrices M.
        Both inputs can be of any shape as long as these 2 conditions are met at the leaf level:
        - p is a 3D (xyz) point
        - M is a right handed 4x4 transformation (4x4) where M[3,:3] is the translation vector

        Result: An array with shape corresponding to [parent matrix shape][point shape]
        ex: p.shape (3, 3, 3)  x  M.shape (2, 4, 4) = (2, 3, 3, 3)
                     P  P  p               M  m  m     M  P  P  p

        ex: p.shape (2, 4, 3, 3)  x  M.shape (6, 3, 4, 4) = (6, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3)
                     P  P  P  p               M  M  m  m     M  M  P  P  P  p
    """
    # Debug input
    print 'p.shape:   %s'%str(p.shape)
    print 'M.shape:   %s'%str(M.shape)

    dot = np.dot(p[...,:3],M[...,:3,:3]) + M[...,3,:3]
    print 'dot.shape: %s'%str(dot.shape)

    # Reorder dot to match our desired output scheme.
    # I won't lie, this part below is a montrous hack that i'm not proud of.
    a = list(dot.shape)
    b = list(M.shape[:-2])
    match = [range(i, i+len(b)) for i in range(len(a))[::-1] if a[i:i+len(b)] == b][0][::-1]

    if match:
        match = match[0:1] + match[1:][::-1]

        diff  = [i for i in range(len(a)) if not i in match]
        indices = match + diff

        print 'indices:   %s'%indices
        dot  = np.transpose(dot,indices)
        print 'dot.shape: %s'%str(dot.shape)


    # Get rid of empty dimentions?
    dot = np.squeeze(dot)

    print 'match:     %s'%str(dot.shape[-len(p.shape):] == p.shape)
    print ''
    print ''
    print dot
    return dot
```

And are some test values:

```
# Sample points to transform.
p = np.array([[-0.023846  , -0.81775031, -0.57507895],
              [-0.86622112, -0.04231112,  0.49786619],
              [ 0.97552607,  0.19235066,  0.10653691]])

# A sample 4x4 Transformation Matrix.
# Translation is set to p[0] so that when multiplied with the 
# inverse matrix, p[...,0,:] = [0,0,0]
M = np.array([[ 0.07396536,  0.77190679,  0.63141827,  0.        ],
              [-0.66843676,  0.50824585, -0.54302713,  0.        ],
              [-0.74008204, -0.38189798,  0.55356346,  0.        ],
              [ p[0][0]   ,  p[0][1]   ,  p[0][2]   ,  1.        ]])


# Different mix and match scenarions, uncomment as you wish
#p = p[0]              # A
#p = np.array([p,p])   # B
#p = np.array([p,p,p]) # C
#M = np.array([M,M,M]) # D
#M = np.array([M,M])   # E

# Inverse M so that result will show that p[...,0,:] = [0,0,0]
I = np.linalg.inv(M)

pointMatrixMultiply(p,I)

# Results:
#p.shape:   (3L, 3L)
#M.shape:   (4L, 4L)
#dot.shape: (3L, 3L)
#match:     True


#[[-0.          0.          0.        ]
 #[ 1.21373736  0.37454991  0.92123126]
 #[ 1.28400743 -0.52477331 -0.74805521]]
```

Unfortunately my flawed scheme gets confused, usually when both points and matrices have similar `container shapes`. And i'm sure i'm making this waaaay more complex than i need it to. So i'm hoping somebody can show me the proper way to get my desired output

Comment: haven't read through your post but sounds like reading the doc of np.dot will answer your question concerning axis handling. If you can't figure out how to use np.dot options to produce what you need, then the more general np.einsum probably will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to make test cases where dimensions differ as much as possible.  So for example if `p` has a last dimension of `3`, the first will anything but 3.  And if the last dimensions of `M` are `(4,4)` I'd avoid use of 4 in the other dimensions as well.  That way if the correct dimensions don't line up I get quick and obvious errors.

```
p.shape (3, 3, 3)  x  M.shape (2, 4, 4) = (2, 3, 3, 3)
         P  P  p               M  m  m     M  P  P  p

p.shape (2, 4, 3, 3)  x  M.shape (6, 3, 4, 4) = (6, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3)
         P  P  P  p               M  M  m  m     M  M  P  P  P  p
```

Does it matter whether the first dimensions are 2d or 1d?  In other words can I combine a `(P,3)` array with a `(M,4,4)`?  Say a (2,3) with a (1,4,4)?

Usually when using `dot` or `einsum` (a potentially useful alternative) one or more of the dimensions match, e.g.

```
np.einsum('ijk,lmk->ijlm',A,B)
# sum on last dimension
(2,3,4),(5,6,4)->(2,3,5,6)
```

Sometimes the arrays shapes almost write the `einsum` expression directly

```
M = np.array([[ 0.07396536,  0.77190679,  0.63141827,  0.        ],
              [-0.66843676,  0.50824585, -0.54302713,  0.        ],
              [-0.74008204, -0.38189798,  0.55356346,  0.        ],
              [ p[0,0]    ,  p[0,1]    ,  p[0,2]    ,  1.        ]])
```

In this expression, `M` looks like a (3,3) array concatenated with a row of `p`, and the extra column.

```
M = np.hstack((np.vstack((m,p[0,:])),np.array([0,0,0,1])[:,None]))
```

With einsum, this expression is:

```
dot = np.dot(p[...,:3],M[...,:3,:3]) + M[...,3,:3]

np.einsum('...i,...ij->...j', p, M[...,:3,:3]) + M[...,3,:3]
```

But why `p[...,:3]`?  Isn't `p` guaranteed to have a size 3 last dim?

How does that last dimension of `p` combine with the last 2 of `M`?  Sum on the 2nd to the last. The addition is the last `row` of `M` (selected on 2nd to the last dim), a `p` like value.  With `:3`, the last column of `M` is not used, right?  In these expressions, the `...` represent exactly the same dimensions (possibly generalized in numpy broadcasting terms).

=====================

Is this the kind of calculation you are doing?

```
In [58]: np.dot(np.ones((2,5,3)),np.ones((7,8,3,3))).shape
Out[58]: (2, 5, 7, 8, 3)
```

The `einsum` equivalent is:

```
In [59]: np.einsum('ijp,klpq->ijklq',np.ones((2,5,3)),np.ones((7,8,3,3))).shape
Out[59]: (2, 5, 7, 8, 3)
```

and just to make sure I am pairing the last dimensions right

```
In [60]: np.dot(np.ones((2,5,3)),np.ones((7,8,3,1))).shape
Out[60]: (2, 5, 7, 8, 1)
In [61]: np.einsum('ijp,klpq->ijklq',np.ones((2,5,3)),np.ones((7,8,3,1))).shape
Out[61]: (2, 5, 7, 8, 1)
```

This a case where `dot` is better, since `einsum` iterates on a product dimension space, which with 6 dimensions will get awfully large.

My original einsum is equivalent to:

```
np.einsum('...i,...ij->...j', p, M[...,:3,:3])
np.einsum('ijp,ijpq->ijq`, p, M[...,:3,:3])
```

In other words, it keeps the initial `ij` dimensions coordinated, rather than broadcasting to a large space.

```
In [62]: np.einsum('...p,...pq->...q', np.ones((2,5,3)), np.ones((2,5,3,1))).shape
Out[62]: (2, 5, 1)
```

Comment: You're correct, `p[...,:3]` is unnecessary. `einsum` works great until it hits an operands broadcasting issue. if you do `M = np.array([M,M])`, `np.einsum('...i,...ij->...j', p, M[...,:3,:3]) + M[...,3,:3]` fails, where `np.dot(p,M[...,:3,:3]) + M[...,3,:3]` works but the resulting shape won't be consistent with my desired output format. My function does a (flawed) transpose step to reorder the output. I'll clarify my question this afternoon, but the output i want is always: `M`'s shape with every leaf (4,4) matrix replaced by `p`'s shape with all leaf points transformed by that leaf matrix.

Comment: I added some `einsum` examples.

Comment: Thank you. Your added examples helped me understand how `numpy.dot` reorders values. What i ended up doing is creating 2 variables: `p_ = len(p.shape)-1` and `m_ = len(M.shape)-1`, i then use `dot` to transform the points with: `dot = np.dot(p,M[...,:3,:3]) + M[...,3,:3]`  and after that i transpose using this rule: `dot = dot.transpose(range(p_,p_+m_-1) + range(p_) + [p_+m_-1])`. This gives me the consistent output i was looking for.